# wp_enqueue_script doesn't load in footer every page like it should

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'caffeine_load_scripts'); 

function caffeine_load_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('bootstrap-modal-js' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js', array('jquery'), '1', true);
    wp_register_script('bootstrap-modal-patch-js' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/patch/bootstrap-modal-patch.js', array('jquery'), '1', true);
    wp_register_script('bootstrap-modal-manager-js' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/patch/bootstrap-modalmanager.js', array('jquery'), '1', true);

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css", array(), '1', 'all');

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-modal-js');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-modal-patch-js');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-modal-manager-js');

}
```

It is then followed by this format:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_scripts_home', 99 );
   function remove_scripts_home() {
      if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
       //here I dequeue scripts and styles not used on home page
      }
   }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_scripts_about', 99 );
   function remove_scripts_about() {
      if ( is_page(412) ) {
       //here I dequeue scripts and styles not used on the about page
      }
   }
```

They load in footer on homepage but they load in head on any other page!

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enqueue your scripts and stylesheets conditionally. You can't enqueue and dequeque again.

You need to do something like this

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'caffeine_load_scripts'); 

function caffeine_load_scripts(){
   if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
     <--- Load the scripts you need on homepage, if nothing, leave this empty --->
   }elseif( is_page(412) ) {
     <--- Load scripts for page 412, if nothing, leave this empty ---> 
   }else{
     <--- Load all your scripts --->
   }
```

Or you can use

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'caffeine_load_scripts'); 

function caffeine_load_scripts(){
   if( false == is_front_page() || false == is_home() || false == is_page(412) ) {
     <--- load all your scripts --->
   }
```

if you don't want any scripts loaded on your these pages